# Object assigning in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi

There is an object `product` which has object `manufacturer` as its field. After fetching `manufacturers` from my server, I reassign product's field `manufacturer` with a new data (for example, fetched manufacturer has additional object `avatar` as its field).

```
async componentDidMount() {
  strapi.setToken(this.state.user.jwt);
  const products = await strapi.getEntries('products');
  products.forEach(async product => {
    const manufacturer = await strapi.getEntry('manufacturers', product.manufacturer.id); //fetched manufacturers has additional field "avatar"
    Object.assign(product.manufacturer, manufacturer);
  });

  console.log(products); // product.manufacturer.avatar is not null

  this.setState({
    products
  });
```

Then I'm trying to display avatar in React render().

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.products) return null;
    return(
        {this.state.products ? this.state.products.map(product => (
            // and it says that avatar is null 
            <img src={product.manufacturer.avatar.url} />

            // displays manufacturer with avatar object
            {console.log(product.manufacturer)}
            // says null! 
            {console.log(product.manufacturer.avatar)}
        ))}
    )
}
```

Also when I check state with React Developer Tools, product's field `manufacturer` has object `avatar` and it isn't null.

**UPDATE**:
Thanks to Sergey Suslov

```
strapi.setToken(user.jwt);
      const fetchedProducts = await strapi.getEntries('products');
      const promices = fetchedProducts.map(async fetchedProduct => {
        const manufacturer = await strapi.getEntry('manufacturers', fetchedProduct.manufacturer.id);
        const product = { ...fetchedProduct, manufacturer };

        return product;
      });

      Promise.all(promices).then(products =>
        this.setState({
          products
        })
      );
```

Comment: Don't mutate the state and don't trust console output when you log objects. Also, you don't return <img>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning with the assign method that does not mutate source object, it returns new object as a result, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign.
You need to do semthing like this:
product = {
    ...product,
    manufacturer: your assign statment
} 
Main reason is that your callback function in foreach is asynchronous, js does not wait for all foreach function calls to completed, it keep on running, couse async word, try to use Promise for this, or better try to use actions for async requests, thank librariy or sagas.

Answer (score 0):

It's because at first render, you do not have the `avatar` value. These values are fetched after the first render (`componentDidMount`).

You need to add a test to take that first render into account.

Also, the reason why your console.log is not consistent, is because you are overwriting the value of product, to be more immutable, you should `.map` instead of forEach, and return a copy of your product instead of modifying the existing one.

How I would write it:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        products: []
    }
}

render() {
    return this.state.products.map(product => {
        const {
            avatar = {}
        } = product.manufacturer;
        return (
            <img src={avatar.url} />
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: `this.state = {products: null};` in constructor and
`if (!this.state.products) return null;` in render

Comment: Updated the contructor so you'll have always an array. Avoids a few tests.

Comment: I mean it renders only after all data is fetched